# VoiceOver bug in menu of NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusitem, voiceover

I've run into the following bug using VoiceOver. I'm new to Cocoa programming, so I'm curious if I am doing something wrong, or if there is another way to do this. The following code puts an icon on the menubar, and has a menu with 1 item.

When you turn on VoiceOver (command-F5) and click on the icon, it tells you: "menu (1 items)". However, the second (or sometimes third) time and after, it says "menu (0 items)" even though the menu has not changed.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSStatusItem *status_item;
    NSMenu *menu;

    // The application needs a main menu to run
    NSMenu *mainmenu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setMainMenu:mainmenu];

    menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    NSMenuItem *menuitem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Empty" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    [menu addItem:menuitem];

    status_item = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];

    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"/Library/Widgets/iTunes.wdgt/Images/repeat_one.png"];
    [status_item setImage:image];
    [status_item setMenu:menu];

    [NSApp run];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;   
}
```

You can compile and run this via:

```
gcc -o menubar -Wno-import main.m -lobjc -framework Cocoa && ./menubar
```

I see this behaviour on both Snow Leopard and Lion. Any idea what gives?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Which OSX version do you have?